# C++ SDL collision if blitted to specific surface

Tags: c++, sdl, collision-detection

I have a simple game that includes 2 surfaces that I blit sprites onto. One I blit little squares which your character is supposed to jump over, the second is the surface I blit my characters sprite onto. I want to make a collision detection where it only detects objects that are on the surface my character is NOT on if that makes sense. So essentially think of it like 2 layers, the first one has obstacles, the second has my character. I want it to only detect the sprites as obstacles on the first layer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that comes to mind is the following:
First, seperate the objects per layer, say `std::vector<MyObjects*> CharLayerObjects;` (`std::vector` for when you have more objects on that plane, like environment stuff) and `std::vector<MyObjects*> CollisionLayerObjects;`. Then just test the character against the objects in the `CollisionLayerObjects` vector. Of course, this only works if both surfaces have the same dimensions, but I think that's to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Normally collision detection is performed on abstract geometry rather than pixel data, and as such SDL doesn't provide collision detection functionality. If you use the abstract representation (eg, a square or a circle) then where you blit your surfaces doesn't really make any difference to the collisions - you can compare whichever objects you want regardless of which surfaces have been blitted to other surfaces.